# Retrieve single value from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

i am facing the problem how to retrieve the value from ArrayList. I pass in the value with this code to remove duplicate:

```
Set<List<String>> allTCP=new LinkedHashSet<List<String>>();
     for(int x=0; x < TCPSourceIP.size();x++){
         allTCP.add(Arrays.asList(new String[]{TCPSourceIP.get(x),TCPSourcePort.get(x),TCPDestIP.get(x),TCPDestPort.get(x)}));
     }
```

But now the problem i facing is i do not know how to retrieve the value. The value i pass in is `10.1.1.1, 123, 10.1.1.2, 234` If i use `System.out.println(allTCP)`, then i cannot use each of the value inside the List.I need to get the single value from the array to do proper output such as, `The TCP Source IP is 10.1.1.1 with port 123 to Destination IP 10.1.1.2 with port 234.` Previously i use this code to do output but it did not remove duplicate.

```
for(int x=0; x < TCPSourceIP.size(); x++){
       jTextArea1.append(x+1+")IP " + TCPSourceIP.get(x) +" is sending packet using TCP Port "+ 
         TCPSrcPort.get(x) + " to IP " + TCPDestIP.get(x) + "(" + TCPDestPort.get(x) +")" + 
         " which is non-standard port\n");
```

Can any one give me suggestion on how to retrieve the value from the ArrayList in order for me to do a proper output. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused: allTCP is a Set and not a List. Sets don't have a index access, only lists. So if you want index access, you have to use a List(?)

Comment: @aaron, You just need these 4(Source IP, Port, DestIP, Port) values??.

Comment: @morpheus05
i am sorry for that, i am still new in java, can you please give me any suggestion on how to do this? Can you please show me the example code? I can try with the example code, so i will also know what to be search.

Comment: @Pratik
yup, i need these 4 value after remove duplicate using SET in order for me to do a proper output.

Comment: @Aaron you can use Hashmap where key will be unique so your primary requirements getting fulfilled.

Comment: @Pratik
urm, u mean using Map<String, String> countMap = new HashMap<>(); this code? If i use Map it only allow me to do remove duplicate for 2. I am a bit confused with the naming of it already. Sorry for that.
can u please provide me some of the example code?

Comment: @Aaron, I can provide you example for that but Axel Amthor provided better way. And i too believe you should follow this way in java. Values should be encapsulated in to an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cases like that I prefer to have the values encapsulated in to an object with getters/setters and put instances of those to the lists / hashes:

```
class Route {
   private String sourceIp;
   private Long sourcePort;
   private String destIp;
   private Long destPort;

   public Route(Sting src, Long sport, String dest, Long dport) {
        setSourceIp(src);
        ...
        ... etc.
```

And then

```
ArrayList<Route> allTcp = new ArrayList<Route>();
...
allTcp.add(new Route(src, sport, dst, dport) );
```

This concept would then enable an easy way to find any source, destination, port etc. by putting the complex comparison methods inside class Route.
Any changes to the inner set of Route doesn't interfere with the caller(s).

Comment: In case OP has duplicate Routes, I would also recommend implementing equals/hashCode()...

Comment: @morpheus05 thought about that as well. Implementing a `getHash(...)` and changing the `List` to a `Hashmap` would solve the duplicates problem intrinsically.

Comment: @Axel Amthor
sorry, i get error for the declaration of List which is List<NonStandardPortResult> allTcp = new List<NonStandardPortResult>();
and also the setSourceIP(src);  is the set a library function? do i hv to import any library?

Comment: Show the declaration of your class  `NonStandardPortResult`

Comment: @AxelAmthor
`class NonStandardPortResult{
    private String TCPSourceIP;
    private String TCPSourcePort;
    private String TCPDestIP;
    private String TCPDestPort;
    
    public NonStandardPortResult(String TCPSourceIP, String TCPSourcePort, String TCPDestIP, String TCPDestPort) {
        setTCPSourceIP(TCPSourceIP);
        this.TCPSourcePort = TCPSourcePort;
        this.TCPDestIP = TCPDestIP;
        this.TCPDestPort = TCPDestPort;
    }

}`
the set is what i tried, this is the code i tried previously

Comment: @Aaron List can't be instantiated as it's abstract, changed to ArrayList, sorry for that. Anyway: you didn't implement the setter function, that needs to  be written explicitly __by you__, make yourself familiar with "getters/setters": public metods which access private properties in order to hide implementation from caller.

Comment: @AxelAmthor
ok, thx for your help, i will try it out myself, anything not sure or cannot be solved i will leave a message here. Really thanks.

Comment: Recommendation: there's a kind of common naming convention: Classes (Capital), methods (lower case), properties (lower case) or myMethod (camel case but lower case first char) - that makes it much more easy to read. So instead "TCPSourceIP" name it "sourceIP"